# How to create Virtual Model from 3D model file

Tags: unity-game-engine, dwg

Is there any framework/product  available  to convert dwg file into a virtual reality model. For example bentley navigator

Answer (score 1):

There is no "Virtual reality model". There are specific file extensions like .fbx .obj and many others including .dwg that store 3D mesh information. Then there are applications like Unity or Unreal or SketchFab that can import those files. Last thing you need to figure out is how to ship your build to the VR device.

In case of Unity you just import your model, connect your VR device and press build.